# Porque la funcion no se ejecuta en el primer click en este caso?

Tags: javascript, html5

Lo que intento hacer es que la ultima imagen se ponga al principio al hacer click en el boton, pero el boton solo funciona desde el segundo click, cual es mi error?

```js
function click()
  {
   var button=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
   button[0].addEventListener("click",pasarimg,false);
  }
    
function pasarimg()
     {

      var padre=document.getElementById("padre");
         var ultimo=padre.lastChild;
      var primero=padre.firstChild;
      padre.insertBefore(ultimo,primero)
  }
 
  window.onload=click
```

```css
#padre
{
 position: relative;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
  
}
 .img
{
 position: relative;
 width: 16.166%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 12% 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
button
{
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="padre">  
     
 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xV5iygm.png"></div>
     
     
    
     </div>
 
 <button >click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione yo mismo poniendo firstElementChild y lastElementChild en vez de lastChild y firstChild, aunque aun no se cual es la diferencia

```js
function click()
  {
     var button=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
     button[0].addEventListener("click",pasarimg,false);
  }
function pasarimg()
  {

      var padre=document.getElementById("padre");
       var ultimo=padre.lastElementChild;
    var primero=padre.firstElementChild;
    padre.insertBefore(ultimo,primero)
      padre.insertBefore(ultimo,primero);
  
  }
      window.onload=click
```

```css
 #padre
{
 position: relative;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 white-space: nowrap;
  
}
  .img
{
 position: relative;
 width: 16.166%;
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
 margin-right: 0.5%;
 
 text-align: center;
     padding: 12% 0;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
 z-index: 0;
}
button
  {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="padre">  
     
     <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
              <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
                 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://img.fenixzone.net/i/rBbHXpy.jpeg)"></div>
  
                 <div class="img" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/xV5iygm.png"></div>
     
     
    
     </div>
 
 <button>click</button>
```